# Python " for...in" nested loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: python

I wanted to do nested loop on Python, but the outermost loop won't iterate
My code

```
file1 = open(textFile1.txt)
file2 = open(textFile2.txt)
for line1 in file1:
    for line2 in file2:
        print line1
```

It only prints the first line of `line1`, in which it doesn't iterate through the `file1`.

Can you please point out my mistake?
What I am trying to do is match the `line1` and `line2` using

```
if re.search(line1, line2):
```

So I do need the outermost loop.
What other solution would you suggest?

Edit:
Contents of file1

```
hello
bello
```

Contents of file2

```
hello world
bello world
hello yellow
bello yellow
bellow yellow
```

I want to grep any line in file2 that contains word in file1

Comment: Hi Jane, you'll have to show us what `file1` and `file2` are.

Comment: Perhaps you want `zip(file1, file2)` instead.

Comment: are you opening the same text file twice or is that a typo?

Comment: You could read your files to lists if you want to run you loop ( l1 = [ a for a in f1] )

Comment: Your big issue is that you need to iterate over each file separately, but you are using nested `for` loops here so that the inner loop (`line2`) must finish before reading the next `line1`. Also, are you checking if the first line in `file1` matches the first line in `file2`, the second lines in each file match, etc, or is this a many to one compare?  With `line1` being the pattern, `line2` will match if the pattern is anywhere in it. is this what you are looking for, or is this an exact match check, or ??? This description just doesn't give enough detail for us to be certain of your intent.

Answer (score 1):

An opened file acts as an iterator. Once you iterated it once, i.e. after the first run of the outer loop, it is exhausted.

Instead, you can re-open the file, cache its contents in a list, or reset the position using `file2.seek(0)`.